# Calling functions in other files in Python

Tags: python

I have an exercise which says:

> Make a program where the user inputs x-digit numbers and the program will print them in ascending order. The number of digits(x) will also be given by the user.

It's mandatory that in another file I have to define 3 functions:

1. Function `einaiXPsifia(x,kodikos)` where `x` is the number of digits and `kodikos` is the number.
   This function must check if the number is integer and has *x* digits
2. Function `pareKodikousMeSimaTelous(x,sima)` where `x` is the number of digits and `sima` is the number that terminates the program (in my case the number is 0).
   This function must use the previous function to check if the number `sima` is valid and then input it inside a list
3. Function `afairesiDiplotypwn(lista)` where `lista` is the sorted list from before.
   This function must take a sorted list and remove duplicate numbers

My functions are as follows:

```
def einaiXPsifia(x,kodikos):
"""
einaiXPsifia(int,int) -> boolean

Function that accepts
two parameters and
returns TRUE only
if the value of the parameter
kodikos integer
and x number has digits.
"""
code = str(kodikos)
if (code.isnumeric()) and (len(code) == x):
    result = True
else:
    result = False
return result


def pareKodikousMeSimaTelous(x,sima):
"""
pareKodikousMeSimaTelous(int,int) -> list

Function that accepts
the number of digits
chosen by the user
and the value of the signal
end and returns
a list of all
codes entered by the user.
"""
check = einaiXPsifia(x,sima)
if (sima!=0):
    if (check == True):
        lista.append(sima)
return lista

def afairesiDiplotypwn(lista):
"""
afairesiDiplotypwn(list) -> list

 Function that accepts as
 a parameter CLASSIFIED
 list of numbers and removes
 from the list of duplicates,
 I.e. each number to
 it appears only once.
"""
for duplicate in lista:
    for i in lista:
        if (duplicate[i] == duplicate[i-1]):
            lista.remove(duplicate[i-1])
return lista
```

My main program so far is as follows:

```
from ergasia2_1_synartiseis import einaiXPsifia
from ergasia2_1_synartiseis import pareKodikousMeSimaTelous
from ergasia2_1_synartiseis import afairesiDiplotypwn
lista = []
length = int(input("Please enter the size of numbers: "))
numbers = int(input("Please enter the number and press Return. 0 terminates entering numbers: "))
while (numbers!=0):
check = einaiXPsifia(length,numbers)
if (check != True):
    numbers = int(input("Please enter a valid number: "))
else:
    lista = pareKodikousMeSimaTelous(length,numbers)
    numbers = int(input("Please enter the next number and press Enter. 0 terminates entering numbers: "))
```

My problem is that if I call function pareKodikousMeSimaTelous from the same file it works perfectly but if I call it from another file like here in my code it gives me an error and it's mandatory that the functions are in another file.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Sotiris\Desktop\OUC exercises\Υποχρεωτική εργασία 2\ergasia2_1.py", line 12, in  lista = pareKodikousMeSimaTelous(length,numbers)
>
> File "C:\Users\Sotiris\Desktop\OUC exercises\Υποχρεωτική εργασία 2\ergasia2_1_synartiseis.py", line 35, in pareKodikousMeSimaTelous lista.append(sima) NameError: name 'lista' is not defined

Can someone help me?

Comment: @SotirisKettenis: In this case, Tigerhawk found the problem by looking at your comment, but in future, use the [edit] link to put the code in your question formatted correctly.  That makes it a lot easier to find the important parts of the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

In your main program, you define `lista`:

```
lista = []
```

In the functions file, `pareKodikousMeSimaTelous` refers to `lista`, which is never defined in that file. It worked when everything was in the same file, but when you split it up that function cannot see `lista` in the main program. To solve this, pass in `lista` like you did with `afairesiDiplotypwn`:

```
def pareKodikousMeSimaTelous(x, sima, lista):
```

And then call it appropriately:

```
lista = pareKodikousMeSimaTelous(length, numbers, lista)
```

Note that if you pass in a reference to a mutable object, mutate that object, and don't reassign its reference within the function, there's no need to return it and reassign. So this:

```
l = []
def f(x):
    x.append(0)
f(l)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
l = []
def f(x):
    x.append(0)
    return x
l = f(l)
```

Comment: Ok... So I managed to fix it but now I get this error:                           "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sotiris\Desktop\OUC exercises\Υποχρεωτική εργασία 2\ergasia2_1.py", line 14, in <module>
    new_lista=afairesiDiplotypwn(lista)
  File "C:\Users\Sotiris\Desktop\OUC exercises\Υποχρεωτική εργασία 2\ergasia2_1_synartiseis.py", line 53, in afairesiDiplotypwn
    if (duplicate[i] == duplicate[i-1]):
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable". Can you help again?

Answer (score 0):

The first file probably works, because you just define functions but I you don't call them. Thus python never has to look up `lista` and the error is undetected.

Your problem is caused by the scope of the import. You could define `lista` in the first file. But keep in mind lists are passed by reference!

**file1.py**

```
lista = [] 

def f(a):
    lista.append(a)
    return lista
```

**file2.py**

```
from file1 import f, lista 

ref = f(1)
print lista                  # mutable object lista was changed
print id(ref) == id(lista)   # is true, both reference same list
```